# Returning complex KO ViewModel to controller

Tags: json, knockout.js

I tried to follow this post here [POST a complex viewmodel to a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144527/post-a-complex-viewmodel-to-a-controller) but it was a bit unhelpful.

I have a ViewModel that when I dump the model as JSON on the page looks like this:

```
{
  "selectedCatalog": 7,
  "catalogs": [
    {
      "name": "EDI Outbound",
      "catalogId": 7,
      "enabled": true,
      "aggregate": true
    },
    {
      "name": "CSV Aggregate Outbound",
      "catalogId": 8,
      "enabled": true,
      "aggregate": true
    },
    {
      "name": "CSV Non-Aggregate Outbound",
      "catalogId": 9,
      "enabled": true,
      "aggregate": false
    }
  ],
  "catalogConfiguration": [
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "Active",
      "outboundColumnName": "Active",
      "pdbColumnId": 2,
      "selectedColumn": 2
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "Category",
      "outboundColumnName": "Category",
      "pdbColumnId": 3,
      "selectedColumn": 3
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "Inventory",
      "outboundColumnName": "Inventory",
      "pdbColumnId": 4,
      "selectedColumn": 4
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "Manufacturer",
      "outboundColumnName": "Manufacturer",
      "pdbColumnId": 5,
      "selectedColumn": 5
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "ManufacturerSKU",
      "outboundColumnName": "ManufacturerSKU",
      "pdbColumnId": 6,
      "selectedColumn": 6
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "MSRP",
      "outboundColumnName": "MSRP",
      "pdbColumnId": 7,
      "selectedColumn": 7
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "Name",
      "outboundColumnName": "Name",
      "pdbColumnId": 8,
      "selectedColumn": 8
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "Price",
      "outboundColumnName": "Price",
      "pdbColumnId": 9,
      "selectedColumn": 9
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "SKU",
      "outboundColumnName": "SKU",
      "pdbColumnId": 10,
      "selectedColumn": 10
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "UPC",
      "outboundColumnName": "UPC",
      "pdbColumnId": 11,
      "selectedColumn": 11
    },
    {
      "pdbColumnName": "Weight",
      "outboundColumnName": "Weight",
      "pdbColumnId": 12,
      "selectedColumn": 12
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure how to get this into my controller to work with.  I am able to post back but the string is null from the following:
Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public void UpdateCatalog(string data)
        {
            var heh = data;
        }
```

View

```
function CatalogConfigurationModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.pdbColumnName = ko.observable(data.PDBColumnName);
    self.outboundColumnName = ko.observable(data.OutboundColumnName);
    self.pdbColumnId = ko.observable(data.PDBColumnId);
    self.selectedColumn = ko.observable(data.ConfiguredColumnId);
}

function CatalogList(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.catalogId = ko.observable(data.Id);
    self.enabled = ko.observable(data.Enabled);
    self.aggregate = ko.observable(data.Aggregate);
}


var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.submitChanges = function() {
        var data = ko.toJS(ViewModel);
        $.post('/PDBConfig/UpdateCatalog/',
            data,
            function(status) {
                alert(status);
            });
    };
    //self.catalogs = ko.observableArray([
    //new CatalogList('EDI Outbound', 2, 1),
    //new CatalogList('CSV Outbound', 1, 1)
    //]);

    self.selectedCatalog = ko.observable();
    self.catalogs = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.catalogConfiguration = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON(
        "/PDBConfig/GetCatalogList/",
        function (data) {
            var mappedTasks = $.map(data, function (item) { return new CatalogList(item) });
            self.catalogs(mappedTasks);
            self.selectedCatalog(self.catalogs[1]);
            $.getJSON(
            "/PDBConfig/GetCatalogConfig/",
            { id: data[0].Id },
            function (catalogData) {
                var mappedCatalog = $.map(catalogData, function (item) { return new CatalogConfigurationModel(item) });
                self.catalogConfiguration(mappedCatalog);
            });

        });


};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var model = new ViewModel();

    model.selectedCatalog.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        $.getJSON(
            "/PDBConfig/GetCatalogConfig/",
            { id: newValue },
            function (catalogData) {
                var mappedCatalog = $.map(catalogData, function (item) { return new CatalogConfigurationModel(item) });
                model.catalogConfiguration(mappedCatalog);
            });
    });

    ko.applyBindings(model);
```

So the question is where do I start for mapping this back in C#  Do I create a model with the same naming convention that is in my JSON string?

Comment: Added the rest of my view for reference.  I am not sure if I need to make the values within my arrays match the naming convention I would put in a c# model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, if you pass it in to your controller as a string, that's all it really is. The Newtonsoft JSonNet Convertor ( http://www.newtonsoft.com/json ) is the framework we use to handle these conversions.

With this library, you can pass the string directly into your object as such:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonNetResult UpdateCatalog (UpdateCatalogModel data) { ... }
```

You can also use the serializer methods to convert your string over to an object after passing it into your controller.

If you have any questions on implementation of this library, visit the SO group:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net

Comment: Problem is the string is always null when I post.

Comment: use ko.toJSON instead of ko.toJS...you may have an old(er) ko library

Comment: Added the rest of my knockout for reference.  Still null after changing.

Comment: you should be passing 'self' instead of 'ViewModel'

Comment: Also null, I want to put together a model to map it to but with the different arrays and the other observables i'm not sure how to handle all that and what naming is enforced.

Comment: What are you 'dumping' then? I'm getting confused at your underlying question. Is it converting a JSON object into a server object or is it more knockout-specific?

Comment: I am calling `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>` to view the ViewModel as JSON on the webpage just to validate the data as it changes with interaction.  I want to convert the knockout viewmodel into a server side object.  Sorry for the confusion, been working on this all day and getting a little fuzzy. So the toJSON works on the page but the post does not work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51132/discussion-between-beauxjames-and-zach-m)